# Fall time for integrator with a large resistor

Tags: dc, time, integrator

I know how to find the Outputvoltage when the circuit is "turned on" (Input x DCgain x (1-exp(-t/a)) , a=time constant , t=time )..but..

How to calculate  how fast the output voltage will go to zero when the circuit is suplied with e.g. 0 V DC.

Thanks in advance  :)[image: Simulation in LT-SPICE]

Answer (score 1):

The circuit you have drawn is NOT an integrator - it is a unity gain inverting amplifier with a low-pass 3dB cut-off of 0.053 Hz.

If you put +2V on the input, the output would become -2V i.e. it wouldn't go to zero. It would reach 99% of -2V in approximately 5*C*R seconds = 15 seconds.

Here's a picture of the frequency response for the low pass and the high pass filter: -

[image]

Picture stolen from [here](http://fourier.eng.hmc.edu/e84/lectures/opamp/node5.html)

Comment: In my book (Microelectronic circuits by Sedra/smith" its called "The miller integrator with a large resistance[..]", so thats why i call it a Integrator :)

If you look on the picture you can see that the input  voltage(DC) goes from -2 to zero after 6 seconds. Can i calculate the output voltage after.. let us say 8 sec. ?